# Is it possible to transmit a packet while the network interface is blocked using netif_stop_queue?

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to implement a time-slotted queueing algorithm for wifi mesh networks, using a loadable kernel module. During certain slots, packets from higher layers are allowed to pass through the `wlan` interface, while in the remaining slots, they must be queued up, to be transmitted in a later slot. I tried the `netif_stop_queue` and `netif_wake_queue` APIs to block and later unblock the interface, and so far, this has been working fine.

Now the hard part: I need to exchange some control packets over the wlan during all slots i.e. even during those slots in which the wlan interface is blocked using `netif_stop_queue`. `dev_queue_xmit` fails during these slots, as expected. I even tried calling the `ndo_start_xmit` (traditionally `hard_start_xmit`) function pointer of the wlan driver, but without consequences. Could you please point out some methods/links by which I can bypass the device's transmission queue and send out packets on the wire??

Thanks